# How to not show alert if file input is empty?

Tags: jquery

```
var $imagefile = $('<input />')
    .attr({
        type: 'file',
        name: 'imageFile',
        id: 'imageFile'
    });
```

Above is my code which creates a file input.

Below is the code which checks if a file format is correct in a table row:

```
function validation() {

    var marks = parseInt($("#total-weight").text());    
    var _qid = "";
    var _msg = "";


    var allowedTypes = ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png"];

    var path = $("#imageFile").val();
    var ext = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

    var alertValidation = "";
    // Note, this is just so it's declared...
    $("tr.optionAndAnswer").each(function() {


        _qid = $("td.qid",this).text();
        _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";


        $("#imageFile",this).each(function() {

            if ($.inArray(ext, allowedTypes) < 0) {
                alertValidation += '\n\u2022 Unsupported file type';
            }

            if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }
        });

        if(alertValidation != ""){
            return false;
        }
    });


    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(_msg + alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now this works fine by recognising which file type is correct and incorrect. The problem is though that if in all table rows the user does not select a file, then it comes up with the alert which is incorrect.

How can I get it so that it also allows a blank file input where the user does not select a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this routine

```
$("#imageFile",this).each(function() {

        if ($.inArray(ext, allowedTypes) < 0) {
            alertValidation += '\n\u2022 Unsupported file type';
        }

        if (alertValidation != "") {
            return false; //Stop the each loop 
        }
    });
```

You should check to see if it has a value, and if so, continue processing. Something like this:

```
$("#imageFile",this).each(function() {
    if($(this).val().length) {
        // continue on
    }
});
```

---

After our comments, you should probably be using a class selector instead of an id selector. So your creation code should probably look like:

```
var $imagefile = $('<input />')
.attr({
    type: 'file',
    name: 'imageFile',
    class: 'imageFile'
});
```

And your routine should be:

```
$(".imageFile",this).each(...
```

That way you **can** iterate over a collection.

Comment: Hi, just one little question, If I have two table rows which both has a file input, if I choose a bitmap file for the first row and a png for second row, it does not display an alert when it actually should show an alert for the first row because it is a bitmap, why is it not showing the alert message for this?

Comment: I think it might have to do with you using an `id` attribute for your file type selector. You can only have an `id` once per page, and if you have more than one, the subsequent `ids` replace the previous ones in the DOM. So in your example, the second file type input **has** a valid filetype - hence no alert. Does that help?

Comment: I have change the #imageFile to .imageFile but still same problem. If first row is bitmap and second row png, it shows error, but if it was other way round, it does not show error?

Comment: That's not what you stated in your first comment.... Which is it? You should probably also have different names for each of your inputs...

Comment: yeah sorry ignore the first comment it is definetly second comment which needs to be addressed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7401/discussion-between-daniel0mullins-and-user1182476)